# c# call method from string

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have several methods called setAnswer1, setAnswer2, setAnswer3, etc and I want to be able to use some variable to call each one within the same method just raising the number on the end by one each time.

So far I have:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string current = "setAnswers" + x;
    Type thisType = this.GetType();
    MethodInfo current = thisType.GetMethod();
    current.Invoke(tihs);
    //MessageBox.Show x;
    setTest();
    if (x <4)
    {
        questionBox.Text = testQuestions[x];
        radioButton1.Text = testAnswers[0];
        radioButton2.Text = testAnswers[1];
        radioButton3.Text = testAnswers[2];
        radioButton4.Text = testAnswers[3];
    }
```

Which calls several methods such as:

```
private static void setAnswers1()
{
    string answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4;

    answer1 = "1";
    answer2 = "2";
    answer3 = "3";
    answer4 = "4";
    answer = 3;
    //Store the answers to question one in array.
    testAnswers[0] = answer1;
    testAnswers[1] = answer2;
    testAnswers[2] = answer3;
    testAnswers[3] = answer4;

}
```

I'm looking to just be able to call and run several methods.

Comment: `string current = "setAnswers" + x;` and `MethodInfo current = thisType.GetMethod();` this won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Put your 'x' into the sender. Simplest way is to use the tag-property.

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Tag = 1;
btn.Click += buttung_click
```

Attach all your Click methods to the same target method, just use different indexes (starting from 0).

as a property of your class

```
 string[] answers = new string[4] {"1", "2", "3", 4"};
 int[] counter = new int[4];
```

and inside your click method

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  int index = (int)((Button)sender).Tag;
  counter[index]++;
  string answer = answers[index];
}
```

But it's not completly clear what you need.
You can also build an array of delegates the same way.

Answer (score 0):

First, make the setAnswers methods as public 
Second, get the type of the class which has your method, let's call it Program

```
var program = typeof(Program);
```

Then, use the GetMethod() to get reference to your method

```
var method = program.GetMethod("setAnswers" + x);
```

After that you can call it by using line

```
method?.Invoke(program.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes), new object[] { /* Pass any arguments if accepted by the method*/ });
```

You can also use this line in this case

```
method?.Invoke(null, null);
```

Hope this would help.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up program logic and program data. You should not program the answers in code, you should program code which reads the answers from a (database/file)

---

But here's an example how to avoid reflection. Reflection makes it more complicated and error prone. By using reflection, the calls aren't checked at compile-time, you'll get errors while running the software. 
The program code you describes isn't dynamic. All methods exists in the same program.

You could use an `Action` array for that. For example:

```
private Action[] _questions;
private int _currentQuestion;

public void Initialize()
{
    // Fill the array ones with the method pointers. Don't forget to call this.
    _questions = new Action[] { setQuestion1, setQuestion2, setQuestion3, setQuestion4 };
}

public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_currentQuestion < 4)
        // execute the Action on the _currentQuesting index.
        _questions[_currentQuestion]();  // <-- add () behind to execute them
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Finished");

    _currentQuestion++;
}

public void setQuestion1()
{
}

public void setQuestion2()
{
}

public void setQuestion3()
{
}

public void setQuestion4()
{
}
```

Like I said, i'm not a big fan of mixing up logic and data, but for learning purpose, it's fine.